# Split and Replace string in Angular 8 HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I am receiving data from REST api. For name parameter, I want to split it at 2330 and give new line break.
Example: I have name: `ABCD 2330 This is My Name` I want to give different style to the split strings and the output on my screen to be:

```
ABCD 2330
This is My Name // this will be bold
```

and not

```
ABCD 2330 This is My Name
```

Given the complexity of my object, I don't think I can put this operation in the ts file. I am binding the data like: `<li>{{data.name}}</li>`
can I use some pipe like split and how would I add /n after the split and rejoin the string and also how can I give different style in the same

tag?

Comment: For every name parameter, you will get the value like that only?

Comment: yes ABCD 2330 is common to all the names

Comment: you should look into writing a custom `pipe` for your template. Angular's documentation is great resource to do so. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations

Comment: @joshvito can you tell me how would this work, I am fairly new to angular and I already tried going through the documentation but it was not a great help. If possible can you explain it in a better way as to how to approach the issue?

Comment: I tried the same thing but it is not showing anything in my case. It is working fine in stackblitz but not sure what is the issue on my screen

Comment: It worked. Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try like below

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'texttransform'})
export class TextTransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    const splitBy = '2330'
    const splittedText = value.split( splitBy );
    return `${ splittedText[0] } ${ splitBy } <br> <b>${ splittedText[1] }</b>`;
  }
}
```

And in the template file

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of receivedData" [innerHTML]="data.name | texttransform"></li>
</ul>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nyt89h?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: In this code, can you tell me how HTML would work? I mean I have 
```
*ngFor = let data of receivedData>
<li name="name">{{data.name}}</li>
```

Comment: I tried giving innerHTML, how can I do that? It is giving errors

Comment: I have created the pipe but I am not sure how this would work here

Comment: name is a parameter inside the object named receivedData, how should I write HTML in this case?

Comment: @Bitly updated the html and stackblitz, you can check now

Answer (score 1):

For a simple use case it might not be necessary to add a pipe.

I've done the following

In .ts

```
myName;

// data received
handleData(data) {
  var originalName = data.name;
  this.myName = originalName.split("name")[0]
}
```

In the .html

```
{{myName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just have to make custom pipe and use that pipe in your html to format the string as per your requirement.

To make the custom pipe use the following lines of code:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myPipe' })
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any) {
        if (value) {
           let firstLine= value.substr(0,9);
           let secondLine= value.substr(9).bold();
           
            return firstLine+'/n'+secondLine
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```